# How can i set png icon collection with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have seen in many examples and jquery plugins and CSS styled htmlElements
that they set icons of an image with several icons.

I want to do that practice with my apps.

[image: icons array PNG]

for example in that image, how can I choose one in CSS? or what is the correct way to choose one of them??

Any examples?

thank you!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: [CSS Sprites](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: @AlexK.thank you. that is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with CSS here is that you are displaying the whole image, but it's translated, and clipped by its parent, either by setting it as a background or as an image that is absolute positioned and `overflow: hidden`.

For example, let's assume the following HTML:

```
<div class="sprite-images checkbox"></div>
```

And let's assume that the checkbox we want to show is at `(32, 32)` in the spritesheet, and is 32x32px in size.

Then, your CSS would look something like this:

```
.sprite-images{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block; // this doesn't matter too much, but can't be inline
}

.sprite-images.checkbox{
    background-image: url("images/my_spritesheet.png"); // <-- insert spritesheet url
    background-position: 32px 32px; // <-- these are the spritesheet coords for the actual icon
}
```

And it's as simple as that. That `background-image` will automatically be clipped by the div itself, which we've already set to the sprite size of 32x32, so it's just a matter of  translating it in the background so only the sprite you want is visible.